WsError occurred in send_and_confirm_transactions_in_parallel()
When I follow the steps in answer of the post related to : send_and_confirm_transactions_in_parallel
From time to time, errors occurred:
The application panicked (crashed).
Message:  called Result::unwrap() on an Err value: WsError(Protocol(ResetWithoutClosingHandshake))
Location: /home/ubuntu/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/solana-tpu-client-1.18.23/src/nonblocking/tpu_client.rs:787
I check the the solana(tpu_client.rs) source code snippet:
                drop(notifications);
                if let Some(pubsub_client) = pubsub_client {
                    pubsub_client.shutdown().await.unwrap();
                };

Any one has solutions or work around? Thanks.
My source code related follows:
    let connection_cache = ConnectionCache::new_quic("connection_cache_my_quic", 1);

    let transaction_errors = match connection_cache {
        ConnectionCache::Quic(cache) => {
            let tpu_client = TpuClient::new_with_connection_cache(
                rpc_client.clone(),
                websocket_url.clone().as_str(),
                TpuClientConfig::default(),
                cache,
            )
            .await?;
            send_and_confirm_transactions_in_parallel(
                rpc_client.clone(),
                Some(tpu_client),
                messages,
                &[signer],
                config,
            )
            .await
        },

        _ => return Err(format!("unsupported connection cache").into()),
    }
    .map_err(|err| format!("Data writes to account failed: {err}"))?
    .into_iter()
    .flatten()
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();


This could be due to some older code -- have you tried using the v2 crates instead of v1.18?

Thanks. I have not tried v2 yet, but the problem should come from the RPC service provider.
Another related question is, could you advise how can I get tx signature using send_and_confirm_transactions_in_parallel() just like the rpc call returned.

Please ask a separate question for that, and someone will be happy to help :-)

Thank you very much! I will ask.
